# Change errpt logs language for AIX systems

Tags: aix, locale

I have AIX 6.X and 7.X systems installed having FR as the default language; as expected, the `errpt` command's output is in FR. Is there a way I can generate the errpt logs in EN without changing its default system language?

Comment: I don't suppose the logs are translated if you do `LANG=fr_FR errpt -a` ? The [AIX 7.2 knowledge center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.nlsgdrf/support_languages_locales.htm) indicates English and French are "Translated" although it's recently introduced (7.1.2.0). Curious to see if the above translates for you.

Comment: did anything happen with my suggestion above?